# Не записываются строки в файл

Tags: c, строки, файлы, вывод, ввод

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct list
{
    char sur;
    char ball;
    char mark;
};
FILE* fl;
struct list stud;
char std[] = "stud.txt";
int main()
{
    fl  = fopen(std, "w");
    printf("Enter Surname student: ");
    scanf("%s", &(stud.sur));
    fprintf(fl, "%s", stud.sur);
    printf("Enter student scores:");
    fscanf(fl, "%d", stud.ball);
    fprintf(fl, "%d", stud.ball);
    fclose(fl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как вы планируете в *1 символ* записывать строку:

```
scanf("%s",&(stud.sur));
```

Или в символьную переменную - целое число (да еще и не с клавиатуры, а из только что созданного *для записи* файла:

```
fscanf(fl,"%d",stud.ball);
```

Ну хотя бы так для начала:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct list
{
    char sur[128];
    int  ball;
    int  mark;
};
FILE* fl;
struct list stud;
char std[] = "stud.txt";
int main()
{
    fl  = fopen(std, "w");

    if (fl == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter Surname student: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*1[\n]", stud.sur);
    fprintf(fl, "%s\n", stud.sur);
    printf("Enter student scores:");
    scanf("%d", &stud.ball);
    fprintf(fl, "%d\n", stud.ball);
    fclose(fl);
}
```

А вообще - надо еще проверять корректность ввода, не допускать переполнение буфера etc...

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать строку в файл; Нужен какой то цикл?

Comment: У вас проблема не в записи, а в чтении. Код я привел, смотрите, разбирайтесь... Первый `scanf` такой, чтоб читать именно строку, а не одно слово (что делает `%s`).